# Nginx gives 404 for some files

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, nginx, django

Getting 404 for `/static/js/admin-extra.js` but not for other files, like `/static/admin/js/core.js`

All static files are copied by Django to the static file directory from both my app, and third party apps. My files are the ones that give 404.

checked permissions (for debugging ran as root):

`-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root     1617 Apr  5 12:46 admin-extra.js`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root     1617 Apr  5 12:46 core.js`

both files are identical. As far as I understand.

Logs for erroring files:

```
webserver_1  | 2019/04/05 11:59:59 [error] 7#7: *13 open() "/srv/static-files/js/admin-extra.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/js/admin-extra.js HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
webserver_1  | xx.xx.xx.xx - - [05/Apr/2019:11:59:59 +0000] "GET /static/js/admin-extra.js HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
```

Logs for normal files:

```
webserver_1  | xx.xx.xx.xx - - [05/Apr/2019:12:14:35 +0000] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16378 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your nginx configuration for that site look like?

Comment: Can you please add the file and directory hierarchy and structure into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I was checking the App container, but should have checked Nginx container. Problem was solved by properly describing volumes in docker-compose.yml
Thanks for the comments.